# Create a Anonymous FTP login in existing FTP server

Tags: server, ftp

I have a server that I already have some users on it, with their files etc... But i need a login that does not require a passwd.

I mean, i need to keep my ftp://domain.com secure, with a login request, for those users that have their folders to log in, but i need to share some files with public people, so a login that does not require a passwd is what i need.

Also, read-only and no ssh access for the server.

Is that possible?

Should I install another kind of vsftp server?

Cheers.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ftp-server.html

Comment: Elder Geek, i'm sorry, din't find what I need there.

Comment: You can reduce the risk by taking appropriate steps. I found this discussion which you may find interesting: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=41040